# Duplication of actions on arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I am writing a script to inventory computers according to different parameters. In one of the parts of the script, I need to add information about the territory from which the CSV-file was received.
To add a property to the beginning of each array, I wrote a function:

```
function Add-LocationProperty ($Array, $LocationName)
{
    $Array | ForEach-Object {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Location -Value "$LocationName"}

    $OrderSelection = @()
    $OrderSelection += $Array[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[-1]
    $OrderSelection += $Array[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
    $Array = $Array | Select-Object $OrderSelection
    
    Return $Array
}

$IpConfCSV = Add-LocationProperty -Array $IpConfCSV -LocationName $LocationName
$OSCSV = Add-LocationProperty -Array $OSCSV -LocationName $Location.Name
$SoftCSV = Add-LocationProperty -Array $SoftCSV -LocationName $LocationName
$CPUcsv = Add-LocationProperty -Array $CPUcsv -LocationName $LocationName
$RAMcsv = Add-LocationProperty -Array $RAMcsv -LocationName $LocationName
$DiskCSV = Add-LocationProperty -Array $DiskCSV -LocationName $LocationName
$SMBcsv = Add-LocationProperty -Array $SMBcsv -LocationName $LocationName
```

From the code you can see that I apply the same action to each array. Is there any way to shorten the code, for example, by using a loop?
The code below didn't work:

```
$IpConfCSV, $OSCSV, $SoftCSV, $CPUcsv, $RAMcsv, $DiskCSV, $SMBcsv | ForEach-Object {$ = Add-LocationProperty -Array $ -LocationName $LocationName}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) You probably meant `$_`

```
$IpConfCSV, $OSCSV, $SoftCSV, $CPUcsv, $RAMcsv, $DiskCSV, $SMBcsv | ForEach-Object { Add-LocationProperty -Array $_ -LocationName $LocationName}
```

Note: Assigning `$_` inside the loop will not change the original objects. You would have work with the results afterwards.

2.) Alternatively, use the `foreach` keyword

```
foreach ($item in ($IpConfCSV, $OSCSV, $SoftCSV, $CPUcsv, $RAMcsv, $DiskCSV, $SMBcsv)) {
    Add-LocationProperty -Array $item -LocationName $LocationName
}
```

3.) You could make your life even easier, if you add pipeline-support in your function:

```
filter Add-LocationProperty
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Array,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        $LocationName
    )
    ...
}

$IpConfCSV, $OSCSV, $SoftCSV, $CPUcsv, $RAMcsv, $DiskCSV, $SMBcsv | Add-LocationProperty $LocationName
```

(Note that I've made it a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#filters) now)

Comment: marsze, thank you for your help!
Yes, I meant $_.
I tried both of the options you suggested, but now I end up with arrays in the output, to which the location property is appended at the end. The function should add a property to the beginning of the array.